# Get the loaded state of the kernel - DOWNLOAD_OUT_OF_ONE in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_view) package but when I open file like docx, ppt, and pdf it show kernel out of dated anyone help?

Comment: What error message do you get exactly, when do you get it and what is your code that lead to it?

Comment: i added this package code to display pptx,  xlsx file using file path

Comment: getting this error TBS download complete - -134 - FAIL